# Surjectivity of the inv map in Global class field theory

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of degree $n$. On page 195, in the book Algebraic Number Theory, in the Chapter on Global class field theory by Tate, he writes that the inv map

$$H^2(Gal(L/K),J_L)\stackrel{inv}{\longrightarrow} \Big(\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}\Big)/\mathbb{Z}$$

need not be surjective in general. This seems implicit in the sentence above diagram (9), where he says that, "... the point is that $H^2(L/K,J_L)_{reg}\supset Im(\epsilon_1)$, but they will not in general be equal".

My question: Is the inv map above surjective when $L/K$ is a finite abelian extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. Let us first recap the argument behind the proof of p.196 : to show the final RESULT that $H^2(L/K, C_L)_{reg} = H^2 (L/K, C_L)\cong \frac 1 n \mathbf Z /\mathbf Z$, one first shows that for a certain type of finite "cyclic cyclotomic" extensions $L/K$, the exact sequence (11) is exact; then, by an inductive limit argument, that analogous sequences are exact at the level of ${\bar K}^*$; the bijectivity of $\beta_1$ follows, which allows to conclude. Actually this  implies that  (11) is nothing but the upper exact sequence of $H^2$ in diagram (2) coming from the exact sequence of $G(L/K)$-modules $1 \to L^* \to J_L \to C_L \to 1$ (using Hilbert's 90 which says that $H^1(L/K, L^*)=0$). One can naturally extend (11) further to the right: ...$\to H^2 (L/K, C_L) \to H^3(L/K, L^*) \to ...$ If $L/K$ is cyclic, $H^3(L/K,L^*)\cong H^1(L/K,L^*)=0$, but in general ($L/K$ abelian or not), $H^3(L/K,L^*)$ is cyclic of order $n/n_0$ = the global degree divided by the l.c.m. of the local degrees, and the cohomological exact sequence stops there because $H^3(L/K,J_L) = 0$ (look at the local components).

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible that $n=n_0$ in the case $L/K$ finite abelian?

Comment: In general, no, unfortunately. The point is that the decomposition of primes in a global extension $L/K$ depends not only on $L$, but also heavily on $K$ (in accordance with the "philosophy" of CFT). NB: the map $H^2(G, J_L) \to H^2(G, C_L)$ is explicit. After identifying $H^2(G_v, {L_v}^*)$ with $\frac 1 {n_v} Z / Z$, and $H^2(G, C_L)$ with $\frac 1 {n} Z / Z$, it is just the map "sum of components".

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me the easiest case for which $n>n_0$? Or some way of constructing an example in which $n>n_0$.

Comment: The answer to your question is not at all trivial. The hard problem lurking behind the scene is the construction of a global extension having prescribed local behaviour. Restricting to abelian extensions L/K, one can use the machinery of local-global CFT like in Artin-Tate "Class Field Theory", chap. X (around  the so called Grunwald theorem).  Thm.5 *op. cit.* in particular gives you an answer: roughly speaking, it says that, given a finite set of primes of K and local extensions of degrees $n_v$ for $v\in S$, one can "almost always" construct a global L/K s.t. $n=n_0$. This seems...

Comment: ... to be in the opposite direction  of what you want, but the gist of the locution "almost always" is that, in specific particular cases , the "best" $n$ you can get is $2 n_0$ .

Comment: Thank you very much for this discussion. Since I am starting with an $n$, I will rephrase your last sentence as, the best "$n_0$" you can get is $n/2$. Does that make sense, and if it does, does it mean that things are fine if $n$ is odd? I am currently reading Cassells-Frohlich and have completed going through Artin's chapter on Global Class Field theory. With this background in mind, could you suggest a more recent reference for the Theorem you state.

Comment: You have to read the theorem 5 in Artin-Tate to get the precise meaning: the local extensions $L_v/K_v$of degree $n_v$ are given, and you want to construct a global extension $L/K$ of degree $n$ s.t. its completions at the $v\in S$ are the given ones.